# Creating multiple vectors

Tags: python, vpython

So lets say I have a list of numbers and I want to create a vector out of all of them in the form (x, 0, 0).  How would I do this?

```
hello = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

So when I access, say, `hello[2]` I get `(3, 0, 0)` instead of just `3`.

Comment: Do you actually want to be able to use that syntax?

Comment: I want to be able to multiply hello[2] (which should be a vector) by another vector, for example.

Comment: If you want to multiply vectors you should use numpy if you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using [numpy](https://numpy.org/) - "the fundamental package for scientific computing with Python":

```
import numpy as np
hello = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
hello = [np.array([n, 0, 0]) for n in hello]
```

The above will produce the results you expect:

```
>>> hello[2]
array([3, 0, 0])

>>> hello[2] * 3
array([9, 0, 0])
```

Comment: just one comment: your example is actually not using any numpy functionality, so just that also can be done with pure Python: hello = [1,2,3,4,5]; hello = [[n,0,0] for n in hello]. Only the multiplication afterwards requires the use of numpy.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with vectors, it's best to use numpy as it has support for lots of vector operations that Python doesn't

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> hello = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
>>> hello = (hello*np.array([(1,0,0)]*10).transpose()).transpose()
>>> hello[2]
array([3, 0, 0])
>>> hello[2]*3
array([9, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
hello = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
new_hello = [(n, 0, 0) for n in hello]
```